# Using two textboxes how do i calculate and display result in textbox2

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have two texboxes textbox1 and textbox2. I want to input a value in textbox1 which will be divided by 250 and the result will appear in textbox2 without using any button.
Example: 500/250 =2
I want textbox2 to automatically display 2 if i input 500 into textbox1.
Pls help

Comment: I have 3 textboxes.
Txtbx1 is empty
Textbx2 has the number '100' (i put this in the txt property)
Textbox3= any value entered into txtbx1 divided by value in textbox2 which is 100.
Without using any button, how do i make textbx3 automatically display the answer when a figure is entered into txtbx1.
Pls somebody help m stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sudo code

define an textchage function on textbox1
purpose of this function is to read value from textbox1 and dividing the value by 250 and writing the divided value in textbox2

so code wise you need to take few steps as described below:

suppose you are using Winforms

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      textbox2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text)/250).ToString();      
}
```

[image: find textchange event here]

[image: put code here]

Comment: Use     `Convert.ToDouble` instead of     `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: Thanks it works but how do i make it allow decimal inputs and results thanks

Comment: Use `Convert.ToDouble` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.